# How do I check the trend of disk utilization in linux(centos specifically)

Tags: linux, bash, centos, diskspace, utilization

I have a centos server which are running MySQL, kafka, and other services, I have separate LVM disks mounted to each of these services.

How do I get the trend of disk utilization for these services? Is there any specific command in Linux through which I can check?

I want to make sure I will not be out of disk space in the coming days.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe you can check `du` command... and you can write a script to check the disk utilization of any directories by scheduling it through your available scheduling tool(cron, autosys etc...)

Comment: Thanks for your response @User123, now my data is already filled at 90% I want to know the trend of last 1 month, weekwise, is there any option to check that?

Answer (score 1):

The [df](https://linux.die.net/man/1/df) command will output the info you desire. you may create a periodic script that checks on it.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Efraim Weiss, now my data is already filled at 90% I want to know the trend of last 1 month, weekwise, is there any option to check that?

Comment: As far as I know - there is no standard linux method of accessing the 'writing trend' of the past, you would have to implement some method of keeping track going forward.
Yet still - if your filesystem is perchance `ext[234]` then you may look at the 'Lifetime writes` field in the superblock, `dumpe2fs -h /dev/<your disk>` | grep -i 'lifetime'` and divide that by the timeframe since the filesystem was created.